# Apache redirect to ignore folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, webserver

I have a self-hosted multi-site Wordpress instance.  There are several different domains attached to this instance - but I don't like the way the URL looks.

So, the actual page URL looks something like this :

http://myblog.mydomain.com/myblog/about-us/contact/

I would like people to click a link that looks like this, and for this URL to appear in the browser address bar :

http://myblog.mydomain.com/about-us/contact/

I want apache webserver to redirect to

http://myblog.mydomain.com/myblog/about-us/contact/

What would the mod_rewrite rule look like ? Should it appear near the top of the http.conf redirects, and be last?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed want to use mod_rewrite.

All rewrite rules abide by the following format:

`RewriteRule pattern substitution [flags]`

You can decide to either place this directly in the `<VirtualHost>` directive of your `httpd.conf`, or into the `.htaccess` file depending on your setup.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myblog/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This will remove `myblog/` from your URL. The `R=301` means that this will be a permanent redirect, and as such, the change will be reflected in the address bar. The `L` declares that this is the last rule, and any rules below will not be applied.